# is there a way to record video after creating exe using pyinstaller

Tags: python, camera, kivy, pyinstaller

I am using Kivy for GUI and developed an desktop exe successfully. The code runs fine which starts camera and even it records video and saves it. But when I create exe, recording is not working. And recorded video needs to be saved but it just saves the file which is actually empty.

I am using windows 10, Anaconda 3.5.5.

this is .spec file

```py
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew, gstreamer

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['ninth.py'],
             pathex=['D:\\Somu_Sir\\new_project'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='ninth',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=True )

coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('D:\\Somu_Sir\\new_project\\required_files\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins + gstreamer.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='ninth')
```

Application is starting but only record function is not working. Expected output should be a video stored in same folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you have to use binaries=[] where you need to pass the .dll files which are required for your application to run. Your code works fine that means your app should also work. only when creating .exe file using PyInstaller you need to give all required files as hiddenimports as well if you want only one single file. You can try binaries=[], where you can add number of .dll dependencies or even through cmd for example:

```py
pyinstaller --add-binary <PATH_TO_PYTHON>\Lib\site-packages\cv2\opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll
```

opencv_ffmpeg320_64.dll can help you to record camera videos